# JAXB XML - Parameter contain value and child parameter

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

Is it possible to have parameter that contain value and together with child parameter? below is the sample.

```
<body>
This is value
<p>This is child value</p>
<b>This is child bold value</b>
</body>
```

If my memory served me right, JAXB give 2 options :-

1. Parameter with the value only without child parameter

> ```
> <body>
> This is Value
> </body>
> ```

2. Parameter with child parameter only without value on parent parameter

> ```
> <body>
> <p>This is child value</p>
> <b>This is child bold value</b>
> </body>
> ```

**Is it possible if i insist want to do like above 1st xml structure? what alternative i can do that?**

add jaxb class code :-

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "PrivElemXHTMLType", namespace = "urn:gs1:ext:xhtml:xsd:3", propOrder = {
    "body"
})
public class PrivElemXHTMLType {

    @XmlMixed
    protected PrivElemBody body;

    public PrivElemBody getB() {
        return body;
    }

    public void setB(PrivElemBody body) {
        this.body = body;
    }
}


@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "PrivElembody", propOrder = {
        "value",
        "b"
    })
@XmlRootElement(name = "body")
public class PrivElemBody
{


//  @XmlMixed
    @XmlValue
    protected String value;

    @XmlElement
    protected String b;
}
```

Comment: JAXB means `XML` binding, above sample doesn't look xml instead a html.

Comment: @Ravi html tag is one of the xml structure. XHTML contain schema that all html tag had.

Comment: I understand that, and I was saying because in html, even you miss end tag, sometimes it works but not in case of xml. Your first example looks weird although it is validate xml example.

Comment: @Ravi yup correct.. that the sample that i had and i need to do it in JAXB implementation.

Comment: Could you share your JAXB class ?

Comment: @Ravi done include the jaxb code.